# How to get the content of an Element (CDATA) while preserving line breaks?

Tags: jdom-2

I tried to get the content of an Element which has only a CDATA section. Inside the CDATA are multiple lines of text.

However when I try `element.getValue()` `.getText()` or `.getTextTrim()` they all strip the line breaks out.

I need to get a String that preserves the linebreaks. What can I do?

Comment: Can you put together an example of your code and perhaps an example of the XML? It's hard to figure out your bug, otherwise.

Comment: So you mean none of these should be removing whitespace? I'm not at the computer at the moment... I just thought maybe I was calling the wrong method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code I put together, based on the example XML file:

> ```
> <root>
>    <data><![CDATA[This is text
>    with some newlines
>    in it, and some other spaces.]]></data>
> </root>
> ```

and the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException, IOException {
    Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build("data/cdata.xml");
    String cdata = doc.getRootElement().getChild("data").getText();
    System.out.println(cdata);
}
```

which produces the output:

> ```
> This is text
>    with some newlines
>    in it, and some other spaces.
> ```

which implies that it works OK.

Comment: I really have no luck, can you think of anything that might cause the line breaks to be removed? they are definitely gone if I use `Element.getValue()` or `.getText()`. I even saved the strings to files to test. Both there and in the debugger, there are no line breaks. My source XML has many line breaks (there is a full page of text in the CDATA section). It uses an Xml Schema, do you think that makes a difference?

Comment: oh... I just realized it is a token in my XSD.. that's probably it.. btw - related question - is JDOM2 still under development or at least maintenance?

Comment: Yes, JDOM is still active, got 3.5 million downloads per year, going strong.